# Error installing pyo module

Tags: python, windows, visual-c++, importerror, pyo

Using **Python 3.5.3** on Windows 10.

I am trying to install the **pyo 0.8.6** module but I simply can't.

Firstly, I tried by using the installer provide by [AJAX SOUND STUDIO pyo_0.8.6_py3.5_setup.exe](http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/software/pyo/), but gave me the next error every time I import the module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/OneDrive/Documents/Python/prubas/pyo test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyo import *
  File "C:\Users\Yooma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyo.py", line 21, in <module>
    import pyolib.analysis as analysis
  File "C:\Users\Yooma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyolib\analysis.py", line 32, in <module>
    from ._core import *
  File "C:\Users\Yooma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyolib\_core.py", line 57, in <module>
    from _pyo import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

Then I tried to install the Python 2.7 pyo version with no luck.

Then I tried to install it from [source code](https://github.com/belangeo/pyo) using the next command as admin

```
D:\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Librerías\pyo-master> C:\Users\Yooma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe setup.py install
```

and gave me the next output

```
running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building '_pyo' extension
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DUSE_PORTAUDIO -DUSE_PORTMIDI -DUSE_OSC -IC:\porta
    udio\include -IC:\portmidi\pm_common -Iinclude "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Mega-Nerd\libsndfile\include" -IC:\liblo-0.28 -IC:\pthreads\include -IC:\portmid
    i\porttime -IC:\Users\Yooma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\include -IC:\Users\Yooma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\include "-IC:\Pr
    ogram Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)
    \Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10
    \include\10.0.15063.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\winrt" /Tcsrc/engine\pyomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release
    \src/engine\pyomodule.obj -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-strict-aliasing -O3 -g0
    cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-strict-prototypes'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Then I tried to change the *bin* folder to uppercase `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe` and nothing. *do not ask why*

Then I downgraded Visual C++ 2017 (14.10) to Visual C++ 2015 (14.0) (MSC v.1900) *do not ask why*

And finally I tried to use the [build_installers_win.bat](https://github.com/belangeo/pyo/blob/master/installers/win/build_installers_win.bat) inside the [pyo-master\installers\win](https://github.com/belangeo/pyo/tree/master/installers/win) directory using

```
PS D:\> D:\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Librerías\pyo-master\installers\win\build_installers_win.bat
```

and gave me the next output

```
*** Build installer for python2.7 ***
"Compil32" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
*** Build installer for python3.5 ***
"Compil32" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I am completely lost.

ʰᵉˡᵖ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, [Belangeo](https://github.com/belangeo) said there was a bug on Windows that will fix in the next version for Python 3.6...

I managed to make it work by installing an older version. (0.8.4).